# Chef LWRP - defs/resources execution order

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

I have the following in a LWRP, all it does is exploding an .ear file::

```
action :expand do
    ear_folder = new_resource.target_folder
    temp_folder = "#{::File.join(ear_folder, 'tmp_folder')}"

    expand_ear(new_resource.source, ear_folder)
    expand_wars(ear_folder,temp_folder)

end

def expand_ear(src,dest)
   bash "unzip EAR" do
     cwd dest
     code <<-EOF
     pwd
     ls -l
     jar -xvf #{src}         
     EOF
   end
end

def explode_wars(src,dest)
    Dir.glob("#{basepath}/*.war") do |file|
           ......... ###crete tmp folder, move .war there then unzip it to 'dest'
        end
end
```

When I run this /using Vagrant provide/ the output shows that Chef starts 'expand_ear' and 'expand_wars' in parallel. As a consequence the expand_wars def fails to find all .wars /they are still being extracted. I tried making 'expand_ear' boolean and wrapping 'expand_wars' in :

```
if expand_ear?(src,dest) 
   expand_war 
end
```

but this yields the same result.???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Chef run](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_nodes_chef_run.html) consists of 2 phases, the *compile* and *execution*. During the first phase chef goes through recipes and:

1. if it sees pure ruby code - it gets executed.
2. if it sees resource definition - it is compiled and put into resource collection.

Your problem is that code in `expand_ear` gets compiled - because it's a resource, but the code in `explode_wars` gets executed straight away - because it's pure ruby. There are 2 possible solutions:

Change your expand_ear to define bash resource dynamically:

```
res = Chef::Resource::Bash.new "unzip EAR", run_context
res.cwd dest
res.code <<-EOF
  pwd
  ls -l
  jar -xvf #{src}         
  EOF
res.run_action :run
```

This is pure ruby - and therefore will be executed instead of compiling.

**OR** put your ruby code in explode_wars into ruby_block resource.

```
ruby_block do
  block do
    Dir.glob("#{basepath}/*.war") do |file|
       ......... ###crete tmp folder, move .war there then unzip it to 'dest'
    end
  end
end
```

This way it will be compiled too, and executed only during the 2nd phase.